# How to specify new line OR the end of string in regex?

Tags: java, regex

My Pattern does not work well for all strings because in case it gets to the string that has no further new line `\n` it would throw an exception. How can I modify `(?:L.*?)\\n` so that it will match until `\\n` OR the end of the String?

```
Pattern patternL = Pattern.compile("(?:L of .*?)\\n", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcherL = patternL.matcher(text);
matcherL.find();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple use: `(?:\\n|$)`, so your regular expression becomes:

```
Pattern patternL = Pattern.compile("(?:L of .*?)(?:\\n|$)", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: Curious how `L` is matching for location here?

Comment: @hwnd It isn't. I though the OP didn't want to use the entire word to keep the code small and I did that too.

Comment: Seems the OP possibly made a mistake IMO

Answer (score 2):

For Java, this is what you need to match the end of the line or a single LF character:

```
(\\n|$)
```

Or perhaps

```
(\\r\\n|\\n|$)
```

If you want to be precise about the line break, and include CRLF too

Answer (score 2):

**@Sniffer's** answer on matching line break or end of line is correct, but from the code that you posted above `(?:L of .*?)`, this will not match for `Location` or for that matter any word, except for the letter `L`

```
Pattern patternL = Pattern.compile("Location of .*?(?:\\n|$)", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

`Pattern.MULTILINE` tells Java to accept the anchors `^` and `$` to match at the start and end of each line (otherwise they only match at the start/end of the entire string).

```
Pattern patternL = Pattern.compile("^Location of .*", Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

I went from a non-greedy to greedy match above to *match the most amount possible*, using a non greedy match will *match the least amount possible* unless you use an end of line anchor `$`

See [what I mean by matching least amount possible](http://regex101.com/r/aE5sB2)

Comment: +1 for dropping the `DOTALL` flag and replacing the non-greedy `.*?` with a greedy `.*`.  It would be even more helpful if you explained *why* you did that.